# When I run an application on non SSL, session expiration stops working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise, puma

If I run the application on SSL, login with "remember me", the session expires correctly according to the `config.remember_for`setting. Switching to http:// expires the session ignore `config.remember_for` and reflect `config.timeout_in`.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: sessions are saved per origin which contains the scheme so you wont be able to jsut access them a possible solutino would be to host your website on both and save the session a database to then if the user logs in on the https site download the content

Comment: I don't need to run SSL and non SSL together. I just describe the difference in behavior between the two. Non SSL works correctly, but SSL doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL or non SSL specifies settings

```
config.rememberable_options
```

Also must use host name e.g. "example.com" not only IP.

With "remember me" checked, the session expires after

```
config.remember_for
```

When unchecked "remember me" expires after

```
config.timeout_in
```

All in config/inicializer/devise.rb